# Test `FOR UPDATE` concurrently from go

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a procedure with `SELECT FOR UPDATE` lock. I would like to test it from go concurrently in order to make sure that lock is actually there.

I am using this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
  name varchar primary key
);
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('john');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tickets (
  name varchar PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES person,
  amount integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp (_name varchar, _amount integer) AS
$$
BEGIN
  -- acquire a lock on person row
  PERFORM name FROM person WHERE name = _name FOR UPDATE;
  INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(_name, _amount);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That's pretty dump sample I can provide at this time, but it shows that there is lock must be acquired to queue `sp` calls.

```golang
func TestInsert(t *testing.T) {
    tx, err := db.Begin() // Read Committed level tx
    defer tx.Rollback()

    insertPersonFixtures(tx) // Using this tx to fill database with test data needed by testing SP

    ready1 := make(chan struct{})
    ready2 := make(chan struct{})
    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
      // Must see `prepareSomeData` data in database??
      tx, err := db.BeginTx(context.Background(), &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: sql.LevelReadUncommitted})
      defer tx.Rollback()
      tx.Exec("CALL sp('john', 10)")
      ready1 <- struct{}{}
      <-ready2
      done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    go func() {
      <-ready1
      ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
      defer cancel()

      // Must see `prepareSomeData` data in database??
      tx, err := db.BeginTx(context.Background(), &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: sql.LevelReadUncommitted})
      defer tx.Rollback()
      tx.ExecContext(ctx, "CALL sp(`john`, 20)")
      if err == nil {
            t.Error("No lock", err)
        }
      ready2 <- struct{}{}
    }()
    <-done
}
```

> Also, I expect 2 goroutines to see test data populated in first transaction, but `sp()` fails because it does not see data, which is odd because read uncommitted level means it can see dirty data (by `insertPersonFixtures`).

A by @Brits:

> The SQL standard defines one additional level, READ UNCOMMITTED. In PostgreSQL READ UNCOMMITTED is treated as READ COMMITTED.

What is wrong with this code or perhaps it's a bad way to test RDBMS locks this way? Or I misunderstood isolation levels? In my example I expect the 2nd goroutine to timeout and signal that there is a lock exist.

Is there a straightforward way to clean up database after each test? I am not sure running truncate for each table is easy. Obviously after such idiocy from equal read committed and uncommitted and lack of proper nested transactions it all turns into a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-transaction.html):

> The SQL standard defines one additional level, READ UNCOMMITTED. In
>   PostgreSQL READ UNCOMMITTED is treated as READ COMMITTED.

So it looks like what you are seeing is to be expected (however as you did not provide much info on `sp()` its difficult to comment - providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might result in a better answer).

Note you have a typo in `tx.Exec("CAL sp()")` - checking for errors returned from the various database calls would improve this test case.

*Additional info following your update:*

`` tx.ExecContext(ctx, "CALL sp(`john`, 20)") `` should be `` err = tx.ExecContext(ctx, "CALL sp(`john`, 20)") `` (otherwise you are checking the error returned by begin transaction - best to check both).

You can perform your test by setting a short timeout (say one second - something like `tx.ExecContext(ctx, "SET statement_timeout = 1000)`) before doing the second update and then check that the call fails. this will work because the first transaction will maintain a lock until the second one is committed/rolled back.

> Is there a straightforward way to clean up database after each test?

This depends on your requirements; in this case rolling back the transactions will remove your test data. Truncate works OK but generally you would want some test data to remain so it's not ideal. I generally restore a backup or use a docker container (data restored as part of the build).

Comment: Well, I wonder what another idiocy I can expect from postgresql tbh. Without normal nested transactions it all looks like a data store made on a knee to fight Oracle which had all necessary features decades before.

Comment: I have updated question in order to show how that `sp` looks like. I am guessing that isolation level mess explains why it does not work properly, so also added sub question in the end.

Comment: PostgreSQL uses [Multiversion Concurrency Control](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/mvcc-intro.html) which reduces the need for locks. A lack of support for uncommitted reads seems to be a small price to pay for this. I have updated my answer with some additional info that may provide you with a way forward.

Comment: I just tried to keep example as short as possible, the error handling is omitted on purpose.